# Lazarus, ошибка в функции.

Tags: lazarus

Необходимо реализовать один алгоритм, для этого нужно написать две функции - для нахождения максимума и минимума массива. Вторая работает, а первая возвращает какой-то мусор. На Паскале последний раз писал давно, возможно что-то подзабыл, но на первый взгляд всё верно.

```
function minY(pointsArray: array of integer) : integer;
begin
     ymin := pointsArray[0];

     for i:= 1 to n do
         begin
              if ymin > pointsArray[i] then
                    ymin := pointsArray[i];
         end;

     result := ymin;
end;

function maxY(pointsArray: array of integer) : integer;
begin
     ymax := pointsArray[0];

     for i:= 1 to n do
         begin
              if ymax < pointsArray[i] then
                      ymax := pointsArray[i];
         end;

     result := ymax;
end;
```

Comment: n в глобальной переменной задается?

Comment: Да, это константа.

Comment: @Сергей1991, зачем вам переменные ymin, ymax? притом похоже глобальные, i - тоже глобальная?
В функции есть Result и собственно имя функции в качестве возвращаемой переменной.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, это не меняет сути дела. Ошибка заключалась в выходе за границы массива, т.к. при передаче массива в функцию отсчет ведется с 0 и следовательно правым пределом будет n-1.

Comment: @Сергей1991, это делает ваш вопрос бессмысленным. вы показали код, ошибка в котором возникает из-за причин в коде не присутствующих. вы же не показали как вы массив создавали. а мы типа догадаться должны были в чем суть дела?

Comment: Ошибка была именно в коде, я создал массив [1..5], а вот обратился к его элементам неверно.

Comment: @Сергей1991, укажите, где в приведенном вами коде вы создаете массив 1..5. а также укажите почему n не может например быть -5, а глобальная переменная i не может изменяется из другого потока. ваша ошибка не воспроизводится, вот о чем речь. кроме того, мой комментарий (не ответ) был не по вашей ошибке (которую диагносцировать нереально без дополнительного кода), а по поводу приведенного вами кода.

Comment: Ad absurdum, понимаю...

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, Ваша ошибка - в определении границ массива. Вместо 1 и n необходимо использовать Low и High, тогда и внешние константы не потребуются. То, что в первом случае ошибка не оказалась фатальной, сути не меняет. Low для динамических массивов, конечно, вернёт 0, но всё равно, её использование более наглядно и безопасно.
Ну и как здесь уже отмечали, использование в функции переменных, вроде ymin, которые определены где-то ещё - это плохая практика.